# Use curl to get http code from webpage, using list file

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, curl

Im am struggeling with a script, and are newbie to shell scripting.

I am trying to create a script, that will run curl on several websites, from a source file.

```
    arr_values=()
#Getting list of domains/websites to check, into array. 
read -ra arr_values <<< $(head -n 999 web.csv)

for s in "${arr_values[@]}"; do
#Running curl on each websites from list.
  res=$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" $s)

if [ $res == "200" ]; then 
    echo "OK"; 
elif
    [ $res == "302" ]; then
    echo "OK";
else
    echo "Error";
fi
done
```

But i get code 000 when i run without the if statement. 
if i run it manually, it all works fine. 
And results in a 200 or 302.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the CSV file is this:

```
www.yahoo.com
www.google.ca
```

I.e. one site per line.  Also run `dos2unix` on the file, to ensure it does not have "\r\n" characters at the end of each line.

Then, run this code:

```
#!/bin/bash

arr_values=()
#Getting list of domains/websites to check, into array.
read -ra arr_values <<< $(head -n 999 web.csv)

for s in "${arr_values[@]}"
do
    #Running curl on each websites from list.
    res=$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" $s)

    if [ $res == "200" ]
    then
        echo "OK $s $res";
    elif [ $res == "302" ]
    then
        echo "OK $s $res";
    else
        echo "Error $s $res";
    fi
done
```

And got this output:

```
./t.bash 
Error www.yahoo.com 301
OK www.google.ca 200
```

What was modified:

- if conditions are verified using '=='
- Modified the echo statements a bit to make it easier to debug

Comment: I tried copy your code, and the example domains. 
It resulted in **000r www.google.dk**, and **OK www.example.org 200**

Comment: I have no clue how you can get `000r www.google.dk`, I put www.google.ca...  Sorry.

Comment: hum, is your CSV a windows format file?  Apply a `dos2unix` on it first, to remove the `\r\n`.  That might be the problem from the start!

Comment: That was the issue, tough i created the csv on mac. 
I created a new file, as TXT, and now it works..... 

Thanks!!

Comment: Great, I was starting to question my sanity!  Please accept the answer, I would be greatful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use single brackets around the expression for it i.e. [ and ], not [[ and ]]. Also you can remove the asterisk from the value to check i.e. `"200"`, not `*"200"*`.

Comment: The if statements works fine, it's the CURL that dont work. :)

Comment: @KimSondergaard, ok for the [[]], but still your if statements are wrong.  `if [ $res == 302]` is good, no need for the stars (*), and you must use `==`.  `==` compares strings.  To compare integers, use `-eq`.

Comment: @Nic3500 i corrected it, but the error still lies with the CURL, which is not giving the expected result.

Comment: Print the value of $res, what is it set to?

Comment: hum...  so what are the values in the arr_values then?

Comment: @Nic3500 It contains all the websites to test. With linebreaks, 
www.example.org *New line* www.example2.org *New line* etc...

Comment: Personally I (almost) never use bash arrays. So many tools already operate naturally on lines. And your original file has lines.

Comment: Look at my edited answer, let me know if it does not reflect your test case.